# livewire Quickstart doesnt works

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I am trying to perform the  [Livewire Quickstart](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart). I have installed everything correctly and copied the code as it appears in the example and the dynamic behavior does not work for me. That is, I do not know whether or not it loads the Javascript because nothing appears in the console.

The html:

```html
    @livewireStyles
        </head>
    
        <body>
    
    <livewire:counter/>
    
    @livewireScripts      
        </body>
    </html>
```

The class:

```php
 class Counter extends Component
    {
        // cual propiedad puede accederse por el componente..
        public $count=0;
    
        public function increment()
        {
    
            $this->count++;
        }
    
        public function render()
        {
            return view('livewire.counter');
        }
    
      
    }
```

The button:

```html
<div class="inline-block mr-2 mt-2">
                    {{-- wire: evento que se espera... ='metodo al que llama' --}}
                   <button wire:click="increment" type="button" class="focus:outline-none text-white text-sm py-2.5 px-5 rounded-md bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 hover:shadow-lg">Aumentar</button>
</div>
```

It does not work for me with the `php artisan serve` or with the virtual server that I have created that I also transcribe in case the path is wrong:

<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\cursos\public"
ServerName cursos.test
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\cursos\public ">
Options All
AllowOverride All
Require all granted

Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing any console errors?

Comment: @Digvijay, no, and I don't know how to check such a thing in the browser console. 
Exist an equivalent to a ```console.log ()``` with livewire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Blade file of counter wrap it up into a single div element

```
<div>
<button wire:click="increment" type="button" class="focus:outline-none text-white text-sm py-2.5 px-5 rounded-md bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 hover:shadow-lg">Aumentar</button>
</div>
```

In the Counter component initialize count variable to 0

```
public $count = 0
```

Comment: is wrapped and initialize to 0. doesnt work.

Comment: It did not have a single parent element.. 
I had two
Fixed that works correctly. Thanks.